# How do I use ILmerge in vscode? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge

I am trying to use ILmerge 3.0.41 in Vscode. I have looked online for HOURS with no success. I want to merge: `Program.runtimeconfig.json`, `Program.pdb`, `Program.exe`, `Program.dll`, and `Program.deps.json`. (All of them are in `A:\Program\bin\Debug\net5.0\publish`)

The way I generated them was by doing `dotnet publish` in the visual studio code command prompt. I am using .NET 5.0

Comment: Could you not use the standard [Single file application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file) support in .NET Core/5? ILMerge seems to be make for the .NET Framework - not .NET 5

Comment: ILMerge simply doesn't support .Net 5 (and it's never properly supported satellite assemblies) so you're much better off using the solution that fredrik linked.